# checking input for morse code converter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check the input from the user to make sure that they only enter dots and dashes and any other letters or numbers will give back and error message. Also i wanted to allow the user to enter a space yet when i am converting how can i remove or ignore the white space?

```
string permutations;
        string entered = "";
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Morse Code: \n");
            permutations = Console.ReadLine();
         .
         .
         } while(entered.Length != 0);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string permutations = string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine("Enter Morse Code: \n");
permutations = Console.ReadLine(); // read the console
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(permutations, @"^[-. ]+$"); // true if it only contains whitespaces, dots or dashes
if (isValid) //if input is proper
{
    permutations = permutations.Replace(" ",""); //remove whitespace from string
}
else //input is not proper
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Only dot, dashes and spaces are allowed. \n"); //display error
}
```

Comment: Thanks - i am trying it out now.

Comment: you need to add the namespace of Regex class; like "using System.Text.RegularExpressions;"

Comment: Yep just added it and worked perfect. Thanks for the big help. Also i was wondering if i wanted to ignore white space and just remove it in the converting process how can i do that?

Comment: Trim is already removing any whitespaces; if you mean not to allow whitespaces during data entry you may change the related line to "bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(permutations, @"^[-.]+$");". Then if any whitespaces exist, it will print out error message.

Comment: well i wanted something so that if a user entered "--.-" it will be same even if he entered "--. (space)   -" i wanted both to convert properly to the same output

Comment: @Amina try with both cases and you will end up with same result. To try, add "Console.WriteLine(permutations); Console.ReadLine();" statements to the end of the method.

Comment: `Trim` only removes leading and trailing spaces, not the spaces in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you separate letters by a single space and words by two spaces. Then you can test if your string is well formatted by using a regular expression like this

```
bool ok = Regex.IsMatch(entered, @"^(\.|-)+(\ {1,2}(\.|-)+)*$");
```

Regular expression explained:
`^` is the beginning of the string.
`\.|-` is a dot (escaped with `\` as the dot has a special meaning within Regex) or (`|`) a minus sign.
`+` means one or more repetitions of what's left to it (dot or minus).
`\ {1,2}` one or two spaces (they are followed by dots or minuses again `(\.|-)+`).
`*` repeats the space(s) followed by dots or minuses zero or more times.
`$` is the end of the line.

You can split the string at the spaces with

```
string[] parts = input.Split();
```

Two spaces will create an empty entry. This allows you to detect word boundaries. E.g.

```
"–– ––– .–. ... .  –.–. ––– –.. .".Split();
```

produces the following string array

```
{string[10]}
    [0]: "––"
    [1]: "–––"
    [2]: ".–."
    [3]: "..."
    [4]: "."
    [5]: ""
    [6]: "–.–."
    [7]: "–––"
    [8]: "–.."
    [9]: "."
```

Comment: This is great - i will actually write this down for future reference but i wanted for the user to enter "--.-" or "--.(space)-" and both will be treated the same with same results

Comment: If you simply want to remove spaces you can do this with the `String.Replace` method: `string result = input.Replace(" ", "");`

Comment: You are the best! I will create a different question to mark you as an answer.